# winsound not making noise when trying to play .wav files

Tags: python, wav, winsound

I'm using the winsound module to play .wav file but when I run the script there is no error or anything, the script runs fine but no sound:

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound("1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my code to work by removing the winsound.SND_ASYNC

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound("1.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```